# Is $\nless$ standard notation in Mathematics

Tags: notation, order-theory

I was recently told that $\nless$ symbol doesn't exist. I know $\nless$ is equivalent to $\geq$, but i wondered if $\nless$ exists, or rather, is used in some theorem or math paper or def, etc. Something to have a reference that it actually exists (or that it doesn't).

Comment: I would not say that it was equivalent to $≥$, as in situations with only a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) you might have neither $a>b$, $a<b$, nor $a=b$.    Because of that ambiguity, not a great notation.

Comment: I was using it when working on the naturals

Comment: But it's not great if the notation only makes sense selectively.  If, with partial orders, you understood $a\not < b$ to mean simply "$a$ is not less than $b$" then it works and indeed it is sometimes used in this way.  But I think lots of people take it to mean $a≥b$ as you said, and ambiguity is bad.

Comment: I would submit that $\nless$ must exist and be used in some context strictly by the fact that it's defined as a symbol you are able to use in this formatting language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol does exist and is used. In terms of real numbers, $\not <$ is equivalent to $\ge$, but this is not true for more general orders on sets like [partial orders](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialOrder.html).

A good introductory example of a partial order is that $x<y$ for natural numbers $x,y$ if and only if $x$ is a *proper factor* of $y$. Here, it may be a useful notation. For instance, the true statement $4\not < 6$ ("$4$ is not a factor of $6$") is not equivalent to the false statement $6\le 4$ ("$6$ is a proper factor of $4$, or equal to $4$").

This is a somewhat contrived example, as we would likely use a different symbol to $<$ for any partial order involving natural numbers, to avoid confusion with the "normal" $<$ (and for divisibility we often use $|$ as a symbol). However, we would use $<$ when discussing partial orders in general, or where there is no "standard" usage of $<$ that already applies.

The only case where I would use $\not <$ for cases involving real numbers is informally, for emphasis. For instance, if someone had written $2.4<2.3$ I might write "the mistake here is that $2.4\not <2.3$" or something like that.